# Why am I getting a NoneType HttpRequest with tastypie POST request

Tags: django, tastypie

It works fine on my localhost during development but when I deployed it on the server I get an empty request.

```
class MyPinResource(Resource):
    pin = fields.CharField(attribute='pin', null=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'my-pin'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False
        object_class = ApiObject
        allowed_methods = ['post']

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            return { 'domain': bundle_or_obj.obj }
        else:
            return { 'domain': bundle_or_obj }


    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        site_id = None
        if 'site_id' in request.GET and request.GET['site_id']:
            site_id = request.GET['site_id']
        else:
            LOG.error('site_id is required!')
            raise Exception
```

"error_message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GET'"

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GET'

This error is inside obj_create when there is a call to request.GET

What could be wrong? Is it possible to have an empty request?
Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Which version are you using? Same version in localhost and deployment? https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/800

Comment: I am pretty sure that your problem is with the tastypie version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, the problem is probably the version, checkout this github [issue](http://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/800). You can access the `request` in the `bundle`, if you're using 0.9.12.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was the clearly a version problem! It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the request object through bundle.request as stated in documentation [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#accessing-the-current-request)

Comment: Thanks! you are correct but we did the development on an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Current tastypie version installed from pip is 0.9.12. In this version obj_create get 2 parametars:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
```

instead of:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
```

in the earlier versions.

Now you can get request from bundle with bundle.request.

Comment: Thanks man we decided to go for 0.9.11 since that was our dev environment.