# TastyPie Nested POST failing to add objects - NoneType has no attribute error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a very simple nested model.

```
class Game(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.TextField()
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Activity(models.Model):
  game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name = 'activities')
  type = models.CharField(max_length=4)
  score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

I can create the objects via the admin, and it works smoothly. I have then used TastyPie to create a the API. My resources look like this:

```
class GameResource(ModelResource):
  user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')
  app = fields.ToOneField(AppResource, 'app')
  activities = fields.ToManyField('api.resources.ActivityResource', 'activities', full=True, related_name='activity')

  class Meta:
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'games'
    list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get','put','post','delete']
    authentication = ApiKeyTokenAuthentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = CustomJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])

  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(user=request.user)

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    requestApp = App.objects.get(api_key=request.api_key)
    return super(GameResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, app=requestApp)

  def get_object_list(self, request):
    return super(GameResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(app__api_key=request.api_key)


class ActivityResource(ModelResource): 
  game = fields.ForeignKey(GameResource, 'game')

  class Meta:
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'activities'
    list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get','put','post','delete']
    authentication = ApiKeyTokenAuthentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = CustomJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])

  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(game__user=request.user)

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(ActivityResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request)

  def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(ActivityResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(game__app__api_key=request.api_key)
```

I post from the app this dictionary with the activity nested in the game.

```
{
    name = "Monte";
    description = "To search for the holy grail.";
    user = "/api/v1/users/2/";
    activities =     (
                {
            type = "eggs";
            score = "0.50";
        }
    );
}
```

The result is that the Game is created in the database, but when TastyPie tries to create the nested Activity object it spits out an error. The error says that when it tries to get the list of Activities, it fails to find those that match with the api_key. I don't understand why it's trying to get the objects, and I don't understand where the NoneType came from if it's creating the Game correctly with the app that sent the request. You can see that I find the app that matches the request.api_key and set that as the app for the Game.

```
"error_message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'api_key'"
    super(ActivityResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(game__app__api_key=request.api_key)\n\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'api_key'\n"
```

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with my resources and the way that I'm getting the Actvities?

As a side note... I can POST a dictionary:

```
    {
        game = "/api/v1/games/2/"
        type = "eggs";
        score = "0.50";
    }
```

When I post that to activities, it creates the activity correctly. And when I get the activity through the API it looks just like that.

So the problem isn't in creating the activities, it's only in creating them nested in a Game.

**UPDATE:**

I put some breakpoints in and found that in resource_from_data it's calling obj_update and not sending in the request, thus request = NoneType. Is this a bug in TastyPie?

```
def resource_from_data(self, fk_resource, data, request=None, related_obj=None, related_name=None):
    """
    Given a dictionary-like structure is provided, a fresh related
    resource is created using that data.
    """
    # Try to hydrate the data provided.
    data = dict_strip_unicode_keys(data)
    fk_bundle = fk_resource.build_bundle(data=data, request=request)

    if related_obj:
        fk_bundle.related_obj = related_obj
        fk_bundle.related_name = related_name

    # We need to check to see if updates are allowed on the FK
    # resource. If not, we'll just return a populated bundle instead
    # of mistakenly updating something that should be read-only.
    if not fk_resource.can_update():
        return fk_resource.full_hydrate(fk_bundle)

    try:
        return fk_resource.obj_update(fk_bundle, request, **data)
    except NotFound:
        try:
            # Attempt lookup by primary key
            lookup_kwargs = dict((k, v) for k, v in data.iteritems() if getattr(fk_resource, k).unique)

            if not lookup_kwargs:
                raise NotFound()

            return fk_resource.obj_update(fk_bundle, **lookup_kwargs)
        except NotFound:
            return fk_resource.full_hydrate(fk_bundle)
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return fk_resource.full_hydrate(fk_bundle)
```

Comment: Which version of tastypie do you use?

Comment: Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15014267/112381